# Cauchy-Euler equation set up

Tags: calculus

I have the following 2nd ordered ODE, and I want to
transform it into a cauchy-euler equation to be able to solve it.

```
xy'' - 7xy' + 12y = 0
```

To be a Cauchy-Euler equation it must be that:

The power of x must be the same as the degree of the derivative of the corresponding y, such that we *want* to get the following equation:

```
x^2y'' - 7xy' + 12y =0
```

I have tried taking a derivative of the whole equation than multiplying by x, but still does not give me a proper Cauchy-Euler equation.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't transformable to a Cauchy-Euler equation, and its [solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2ay%27%27%20-%207%2ax%2ay%27%20%2b%2012%2ay%20=%200) comes up in terms of hypergeometric functions and some other weird specialized function.

Likely, what happened is that whoever gave you the problem meant $x^2 y'' - 7 x y' + 12y =0$ and typo'd the problem. Check the errata sheet for your book if its a book problem or go ask whoever gave you the problem.

Comment: its weird since it came from a textbook problem.
and the answer is y = c(x^2 - x^6), where c is any real #.
But i have no clue how they arrived at such answer.

Comment: The solution to $x^2 y'' - 7 x y' + 12y =0$ is $y= c_1 x^2 + c_2 x^6$. So the book has a typo (many freshman/sophomore level textbooks are filled with them, so this should not be a surprise).